# express route return necessary or not

Tags: express

I am using the express framework for my web app. I picked-up some code from a book, look at this code, this a route to a page:

```
app.post('/register', function(req, res) {
  var firstName = req.param('firstName', '');
  var lastName = req.param('lastName', '');
  var email = req.param('email', null);
  var password = req.param('password', null);

  if ( null == email || email.length < 1
       || null == password || password.length < 1 ) {
    res.send(400);
    return;
  }
```

What is the purpose of the `return` here, is it necessary?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `return` is only necessary if you have more code below that point in the route handler function and you want to bypass the rest of the function. Nothing in express will look at or care about the value you return. If you are at the bottom of your function anyway, you may omit the `return` statement entirely.

Typically, you see patterns like:

- first do some prerequisite checking, validation, authorization, or similar logic
- If any of that fails, send and error and return from the function to bypass the main logic. These are called guard clauses.
- Main logic code comes next and only executes if the `return` wasn't encountered.

Comment: (a) I remember seeing response.send() mentioned as non-documented.  I see response.writeHead(STATUS [,...]), response.write(), response.end(). https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_statusmessage_headers (b) Issuing a return without a call to response.end() will leave the response unanswered in the javascript event queue.

Comment: `res.send()` is an express-specific API addition. It takes care of calling `res.end()`. [here's the source](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/dc538f6e810bd462c98ee7e6aae24c64d4b1da93/lib/response.js#L107)

Comment: if code inside the route function creates a promise and you handle the promise immediately with then() and catch() methods, is it still necessary to return the promise for unit testing purposes or how would I go about checking such code?

Answer (score -2):

res.render("view page name",{title:"",data:""});

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.